# Can OpenSSH on Windows Server 2019 employ client certificates created via PowerShell as opposed to ssh-keygen?

Tags: openssh, public-key-encryption

I'm really not sure of the core differences between each, but can OpenSSH on Windows Server 2019 employ client certificates created via PowerShell (*.pfx, *.cer) as opposed to using public/private key pairs (*.pub, *.) generated via ssh-keygen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, but mostly no.

- The OpenSSH client does not understand the X.509 certificate format, nor the PKCS#12 (.pfx) private key format, and it cannot access anything stored in Windows CAPI either. It can use the *keys* themselves, but they must be extracted into the apropriate format first.
- Likewise, the OpenSSH server doesn't let you put X.509 certificates in authorized_keys (you'd have to perform the same public-key extraction), and it has absolutely no idea how to verify them against root authorities either.
- There's a third-party fork, Roumen Petrov's "PKIX-SSH", which supports direct X.509 certificate usage (but I don't think it supports loading .pfx or CAPI private keys; most likely you'll still need to convert them into PEM or PKCS#8 format).
- However, on Windows, you'll probably prefer PuTTY-CAC (a widely used fork of PuTTY) which supports certificates stored in Windows CAPI.

I did *expect* Microsoft to adapt their OpenSSH port to be able to use certificates and keys in CAPI, but they just went with traditional ssh-agent instead...